# WooCommerce get_the_terms category and subcategory order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a woocommerce website and what I'm trying to do is to get subcategories names with and relative links, over the product title.

So i call this action to retrieve the category to display the category before the title:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary' , 'cat_type_before_title', 3);
function cat_type_before_title() {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       $term_link = get_term_link( $term->term_id );
       <!-- this line below is to test the order of all the categories assigned  -->
       echo '<h2><a href="'. $term_link . '">'. $term->name . '</a></h2>';
     }
     //echo '<h2><a href="'. $term_link . '">'. $terms[2]->name . '</a></h2>';
   }
```

The problem I'm having is that the output of the categories it's not always in the order that i would expect.

I have this categories structure:

```
CAT_A
- CAT_B 
-- CAT_C 

CAT_D
- CAT_E
-- CAT_F

..and so..
```

For some reason the output with `$term->name` in the `foreach loop` for some of the categories it's not in the expected order and i have somenthing like :

```
CAT_C
CAT_A 
CAT_B
```

so, for example, if want retrieve the category name i want to print with `$terms[1]->name`  i will expect `CAT_B` but instead i have `CAT_A`.

What i'm missing?
Any help?
Thank you! :)

Comment: You can use `wp_get_post_terms()` insted of `get_the_terms()` to get terms in that function you can use third parms to pass orderby see here [wp_get_post_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/)

Comment: Hi @Bhautik , thank you a lot! this is working! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_get_post_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/) insted of `get_the_terms()` to get terms in that function you can use third parms to pass orderby. check code below.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary' , 'cat_type_before_title', 3);
function cat_type_before_title() {
    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat', array( 'orderby' => 'parent' ) );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term->term_id );
       
        echo '<h2><a href="'. $term_link . '">'. $term->name . '</a></h2>';
    }
        //echo '<h2><a href="'. $term_link . '">'. $terms[2]->name . '</a></h2>';
}
```

Comment: The only thing that I have to add to this is that in my case I had to use `"orderby => "parent""` to have categories in right order.
Thank you again!